# Submit Form afer change Checkbox

Tags: forms, symfony, twig

I want to submit a Form after a checkbox is changed in a twig file like:

```
{{start_form(einrichtungUsersForm.getEinrichtungUserType())}}
{{ form_widget(einrichtungUsersForm.getEinrichtungUserType().active )}}
{{ende_form(einrichtungUsersForm.getEinrichtungUserType())}}
```

Is that possible?

Comment: Yes it’s, Search for Ajax on change function

Comment: [related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840429/what-is-the-difference-between-client-side-and-server-side-programming)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes you can do it with jquery like this :

```
$('body').on('change', '#checkboxId', function() {
    $(this).closest('form').submit();
});
```

If you don't use jquery, this is the solution with javascript :

```
let checkbox = document.getElementById('checkboxId');
checkbox.addEventListener('change' => () {
    this.closest('form').submit();
});
```

Comment: Hey thanks for your help. I don't understand how I trigger the JavaScript.

Comment: hi, you are welcome, i need to see your HTML page

Comment: You  mean like a picture or the html cod? I don't now wat I need to show you. I don't have a lot more Code thar. My problem is that I can't trigger a Button to send the Submit.

Comment: The part of code tha contains your checkbox